# Unexpected Behavior "beforeEdit" Event Handler. Kendo Ui Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, event-handling, kendo-grid

My intention is to hide several columns depending on different "steps" in Kendo UIs' Grid. More specifically i want to show 2 columns hidden with `{field: "id", hidden: true},` with the "beforeEdit" Event Handler.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    save:console.log("save"),
    cancel:console.log("cancel"),
    beforeEdit: console.log("beforeEdit"),
    (...some more code...)
    dataSource: dataSource
```

});

According to the Kendo UI Doc([Link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-show-hidden-on-edit)) these handlers should trigger on editing, saving or cancelling edits. For testing purposes i make a console.log output within these handlers. But no matter what, the handler seems to fire as soon as i open refresh the page.

I'd appreciate any kind on information why this misfeature occur.

With best regards
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad. It is friday... i forgot to define a function within the triggers.

```
save:function(){
    console.log("save")
},
```

Problem solved!

Comment: `cancel` and `beforeEdit` are also invalid.